# Codifferential of wedge of two 1-forms

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $\omega,\eta$ be two 1-forms on a manifold $M$. I'm interested in an expression for
$$
\delta(\omega\wedge\eta)
$$
where $\delta$ is the co-differential operator $\Lambda^2(M)\to\Lambda^1(M)$. Using that, for a general $\xi\in\Lambda^p(M)$
$$
\delta\xi(X_2,\dots,X_p)=-\sum_j(\nabla_{E_j}\xi)(E_j,X_2,\dots,X_p),
$$
where $\{E_j\}$ is any orthonormal frame, I came up with the following formula:
$$
\delta(\omega\wedge\eta)=(\delta\omega)\eta-(\delta\eta)\omega-\omega\cdot\nabla\eta+\eta\cdot\nabla\omega
$$
where
$$
(\omega\cdot\nabla\eta)(Y)=\sum_j\omega(E_j)(\nabla_{E_j}\eta)(Y).
$$
I have the impression that this formula is a little bit unnatural. I tried to look it up but I couldn't find anything explicit, however it still may be a very well-known thing that I'm not aware of. Does anybody know where I could find more informations?

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Since $\delta$ and $\nabla$ are *first* order linear operators defined in terms of a Riemannian metric (and orientation), curvature terms can't appear in the formula for $\delta(\omega\wedge\eta)$.  Thus, if the formula holds in flat space for $\omega=f\,\mathrm{d}x^1$ and $\eta = \mathrm{d}x^2$ (and, by inspection, it evidently does), it will hold for all $\omega$ and $\eta$ on a general Riemannian manifold.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that you have a mistake in your formula:  Note that, for the first two terms on the right hand side, you have $(\delta\omega)\eta-\eta(\delta\omega)$, which is equal to zero.  Did you mean the second term to be $(\delta\eta)\omega$?  Also, you might want to check your constants and signs.

Comment: @RobertBryant You are right, I just edited it. Thank you!